# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "UniswapV2Router02" not found

Tags: uniswap, hardhat, test, fantom, router

I wanna get UniswapV2Router02 deployed on Fantom network.

```
UniswapRouter = await ethers.getContractAt(
      "UniswapV2Router02",
      "0xf491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c29"
);
```

But I get the following error.
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "UniswapV2Router02" not found.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ethers.getContractAt is not ether js native method. Instead it is the variant of hardhat-ethers.

You should use ether.js method.

First go to, fantom scan and take the contract abi and save it in router02.json file.

Then require it to the main file with

```
const {ABI} = require("./router02.json")

require("dotenv").config();

const { ALCHEMY_API_KEY } = process.env;

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
`[FantomAPiURL]/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`
 );

const address = "0xf491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c29";

const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, ABI, provider);
```

That is it. You will get contract instance there and you can function as you like.

If you have any doubts regarding .env file. Look at this answer of mine, I explained it clearly [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136058/error-could-not-detect-network).

Comment if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Thanks. I must provide "provider"? What if I ignore "provider" parameter?

Comment: Without provider, you cannot talk to blockchains. Providers are in fact node providers. Only with the help of them you can query or write the transactions. 


Go to alchemy and create an account. It is pretty much self-explantory. But if you have any doubts, ask me.

Comment: I'm gonna create app on Alchemy but I can't find Fantom on "CHAIN" option.

Comment: I am sorry. I have never tried Fantom so I wasn't sure. But here, quick node can help you!

[https://www.quicknode.com/chains/ftm?utm_term=fantom%20api&utm_campaign=Chain+%7C+Fantom&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&hsa_acc=1365030395&hsa_cam=14241920396&hsa_grp=125927179339&hsa_ad=538490909211&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-1687268561200&hsa_kw=fantom%20api&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7KqZBhCBARIsAI-fTKJk47KogQ-RjFLSf4KDYEMhs7who2wnj52TNlMxTByTF0AVL2xqnL0aAjeOEALw_wcB](quicknode)

Comment: `You should use ether.js method.` - why?  If you're using `hardhat-ethers` then `getContractAs` is certainly available.